# How do I easily set the selected value on the dropdown based on the uniqueid of my return object?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am binding objects to my autocomplete DropDown from my endpoint. How do I easily set the selected value on the dropdown based on the uniqueid of my return object?

The Code sample shows my autocomplete setup. The FKTitleValue is the id of the foreign key ref. The options have objects {id: 'idValue', display:'displayValue'}. I want to compare the FKTitleValue with the options id to select the autocomplete value.

```
      <Autocomplete
            id="FkTitle"
            classes={{
              option: classes.option,
            }}
            options={props.dropDownData.fkTitleDropdownData ?? []}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.display}
            loading={!props.dropDownData.fkTitleDropdownData}
            value={FkTitleValue ?? null}
            onChange={FkTitleOnChange}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                InputProps={{
                  ...params.InputProps,
                  autoComplete: 'new-password',
                  endAdornment: (
                    <React.Fragment>
                      {!props.dropDownData.fkTitleDropdownData ? (
                        <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} />
                      ) : null}
                      {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                    </React.Fragment>
                  ),
                }}
                label="FkTitle"
                variant="outlined"
                margin="normal"
              />
            )}
          />
```

Comment: Some code sample of what you are trying to achieve and the return object would be good to add

Comment: Sure i made the edit above

Comment: what does `props.dropDownData.fkTitleDropdownData` and `FkTitleOnChange` looks like? and I think that you want to use `||` and not `??`

Comment: props.dropDownData.fkTitleDropdownData is an array of  {id: 'idValue', display:'displayValue'}....ill make the || adjustment .... is there a way to loop through or find a value in the options to set selected value to my FkTitleValue